# Prove the determinant is $0$

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, determinant, factorial

This is Problem 16.17 from the book *Exercises in Algebra* by A. I. Kostrikin.

> Prove that
> $$
> \left|\begin{array}{ccccc}
> \dfrac{1}{2 !} & \dfrac{1}{3 !} & \dfrac{1}{4 !} & \cdots & \dfrac{1}{(2 k+2) !} \\
> 1 & \dfrac{1}{2 !} & \dfrac{1}{3 !} & \cdots & \dfrac{1}{(2 k+1) !} \\
> 0 & 1 & \dfrac{1}{2 !} & \cdots & \dfrac{1}{(2 k) !} \\
> \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
> 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & \dfrac{1}{2 !}
> \end{array}\right|=0, \quad k \in \mathbb{N}
> $$

**My Attempt:** I tried to expand it by the first column, but it seemed to be more complicated when I did that. I also tried to add edges to the determinant(in the hope that it will be easier to calculate), but I still failed to work it out.

So, **My Question is**, how to calculate this determinant?

Comment: My first thought would be to reduce it to triangular form.  I would take a reasonable size example, say $k=3$ and keep track of the factors I use to do the reduction.  Then look for a pattern and try to prove it works.

Comment: The hint in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3288338/ gives the recursive formula $d_0 = 1, d_1 = \frac12, d_2 = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac {(-1)^{k+1}}{(k+1)!} d_{n-k}$ for when the determinant is of size $k \times k$. This method probably wouldn't work (considering the fact that the determinant do not vanish for even $k$), and even if it does, it will be terribly unsatisfying.

Comment: There's definitely a pattern in the nullspace. For $k = 1,2,3,4$ we have the following solutions to $Mx = 0$.
$$
(1,-6,12)\\
(1,0,-6,36,-72)\\
(1,0,-42,0,2520,-15120,30240)\\
(1,0,-4,0,1680,0,-100800,604800,-1209600)
$$

Comment: I tried something with the explicit formula which was interesting, although useless.
The relevant permutations satisfy σ(i) ≥ i-1, which is enough to show that σ decomposes into disjoint shift-left-cycles, e.g. (5432). Counting 1-cycles, this corresponds to a partition of $\{1, \ldots, n-1\}$ into consecutive blocks. If these have lengths $j_1, \ldots, j_k$, resp., the contributed summand should be $(-1)^{n-1 + k}\prod_{i=1}^k 1/(j_i+1)!$.
Summing over all $k$ and all such multiindices $J$, this gives the det, but I failed to see anything like e.g. a useful $\pm$-pairing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We want to prove that the $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ matrix
$$
A_n=\pmatrix{
\dfrac{1}{2!} &\dfrac{1}{3!} & \cdots &\cdots & \cdots &\dfrac{1}{n!} \\
1 &\dfrac{1}{2!} &\dfrac{1}{3!} &\cdots &\cdots &\dfrac{1}{(n-1)!} \\
0 & 1 & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots\\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots&\ddots & \vdots\\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots &1& \dfrac{1}{2!} & \dfrac{1}{3!}\\
0 & \cdots & \cdots & 0 & 1 & \dfrac{1}{2!}
}
$$
is singular when $n\ge4$ is even. This can be proved by mathematical induction on $n$. The base case $n=4$ can be verified directly. In the inductive step, note that for any positive integer $m$,
$$
\sum_{k=0}^m\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\frac{1}{(m-k)!}=\frac{1}{m!}\sum_{k=0}^m(-1)^k\binom{m}{k}=\frac{1}{m!}(1-1)^m=0.
$$
Move the first and the last summands out of the sum, we obtain
$$
\frac{1}{m!}+\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\frac{1}{(m-k)!}=\frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{m!}.
$$
Denote the $i$-th row of $A_n$ by $a_i$. The previous identity means that
\begin{aligned}
u&:=a_1+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}a_{k+1}\\
&=\left(-\frac{1}{2!},\,\frac{1}{3!},\,-\frac{1}{4!},\,\frac{1}{5!},\,\ldots,\,-\frac{1}{(n-2)!},\,\frac{1}{(n-1)!},\,\frac{1}{(n-1)!}-\frac{1}{n!}\right).
\end{aligned}
(Note that the last entry of $u$ is not $-\frac{1}{n!}$, because the last column of $A_n$ ends with $\frac{1}{2!}$, not $1$.) In other words, by some appropriate elementary row operations, we can modify the first row of $A$ to $u$. Therefore, by the multilinearity of the determinant function, $\det(A_n)$ remains unchanged if we replace the first row of $A_n$ by
$$
v:=\frac12(a_1+u)
=\left(0,\,\frac{1}{3!},\,0,\,\frac{1}{5!},\,\ldots,\,0,\,\frac{1}{(n-1)!},\,\frac{1}{2\times(n-1)!}\right).
$$
Now suppose $n\ge6$ is even. By Laplace expansion along $v$ and by induction assumption, we get
\begin{aligned}
\det(A_n)
&=-\frac{1}{3!}\det(A_{n-2})-\frac{1}{5!}\det(A_{n-4})-\cdots-\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\det(A_2)+\frac{1}{2\times(n-1)!}\\
&=-\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\det(A_2)+\frac{1}{2\times(n-1)!}\\
&=-\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{2\times(n-1)!}\\
&=0.
\end{aligned}

Answer (score 7):

Finally I found a direct way to work this out, that is, to use [Generating Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function).

---

From this [article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2690455) we get the following proposition:

> **Proposition.** Consider the following infinite matrix with $1$s in the super diagonal.
> $$
> D=\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
> b_{0} & 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdot \\
> b_{1} & c_{1} & 1 & 0 & . \\
> b_{2} & c_{2} & c_{1} & 1 & . \\
> b_{3} & c_{3} & c_{2} & c_{1} & . \\
> b_{4} & c_{4} & c_{3} & c_{2} & . \\
> \cdot & . & . & . & .
> \end{array}\right] 
> $$
> Let $B(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_{n} x^{n},$ and $C(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_{n} x^{n}$ be the generating functions for the sequences $b_{0}, b_{1}, b_{2}, \ldots$ and $c_{1}, c_{2}, c_{3}, \ldots,$ respectively. If
> $$
> A(x)=\frac{B(x)}{1+C(x)}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n+1} x^{n}
> $$
> then $a_{n}=(-1)^{n-1} D_{n}$ and $1+x A(-x)$ is the generating function of $D_{n}$.

For the original problem, it is equivalent to calculate the determinant:
$$
D=\left| \begin{matrix}
 \dfrac{1}{2!}&  1&  0&  \cdots&  0\\
 \dfrac{1}{3!}&  \dfrac{1}{2!}&  1&  \cdots&  0\\
 \dfrac{1}{4!}&  \dfrac{1}{3!}&  \dfrac{1}{2!}&  \cdots&  0\\
 \vdots&  \vdots&  \vdots&  \ddots&  \vdots\\
 \dfrac{1}{\left( 2k+2 \right) !}&  \dfrac{1}{\left( 2k+1 \right) !}&  \dfrac{1}{\left( 2k \right) !}&  \cdots&  \dfrac{1}{2!}\\
\end{matrix} \right|
$$

We can see that $\displaystyle B(x)=\sum _{i=0}^{\infty } \frac{x^{i}}{(i+2)!}= \frac{-x+e^x-1}{x^2}$, $\displaystyle C(x)=\sum _{i=1}^{\infty } \frac{x^i}{(i+1)!} = \frac{-x+e^x-1}{x}$, so $A(x)=\dfrac{1}{x}+\dfrac{1}{1-e^x}$, and finally the generating function for $D_n$ is $D(x)=\dfrac{x}{e^x-1}+x$.

Notice the order $N$ of original matrix $D$ is always *odd* (since $N=(2k+2)-2+1=2k+3$), so the original claim is equivalent to when $n>4$ and $n$ is odd, $[x^n]D(x)=0$. It's easy to see that $D(x) -1 - x/2$ is an even function, which implies its series only contains terms of the form $x^{2k}$, thus we finished our proof.

---

I think this method really requires a good understanding of linear equations and Cramer's Law, along with the knowledge of generating functions.